# How did Pebble official iOS app to get incoming call number?

Tags: ios, pebble-watch

As I said, Pebble's official iOS app already can get incoming call number as of now. And I would very much like to know how? Which framework should I include and what API should I call to do the same? Because last time I checked, apple still doesn't allow such calls. Maybe it's the newly added api in iOS7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the Pebble smartwatch displays the number of an incoming caller, it is not related to the app : it is due to the [Bluetooth Profiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile) implemented by the watch (such as the PBAP profile for example).

The Pebble official app is only used to install new firmwares and watchapps.

Comment: So the pebble watch is actually acting like a bluetooth earphone without mic and speaker. That explained a lot. I guess notifications were sent using the same way by bluetooth profile? Also is it possible for the watch to use bluebooth to send caller number back to the app (using bluetooth possibly)?

Comment: I'm not an expert in Bluetooth but I think that the MAP profile is used to send notifications (anyone confirm ?!). And yes, the Pebble could send back the number of the caller but that would be useless because the phone has all the contacts. However, you can trigger the call via the Pebble.

Comment: PBAR is phone book access. Does that imply the pebble will only display the name if it is in the iPhone contacts app? And not otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the Pebble application is getting the incoming phone number.  It's being presented to the Pebble watch as part of the incoming phone call bluetooth information, just as a bluetooth headset receives the incoming call number.